# Confusion about python multiprocessing timing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to do simple parallel processing using Pool from multiprocessing. Here is the code.

```
from math import sqrt
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from multiprocessing import Pool as WorkerPool
def squareNumber(n):
    return sqrt(n ** 2)

def calculateSeq(numbers):
    results = map(squareNumber, numbers)
    return results

def calculatePar(numbers, threads=4):
    pool = WorkerPool(processes=threads)
    results = pool.map(squareNumber, numbers)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return results

if __name__ == "__main__":
    N = int(10e6)
    numbers = range(N)

    start = timer()
    resultSeq = calculateSeq(numbers)
    end = timer()
    seqtime = (end-start)

    start = timer()
    resultPar = calculatePar(numbers, 4)
    end = timer()
    partime = (end-start)

    print "sequential time : ", seqtime*1e3, " ms"
    print "parallel time : ", partime*1e3, " ms"

    assert resultPar == resultSeq
```

On my machine with 2 cores (4 threads), I achieved the following timings:

```
sequential time :  2532.51695633  ms
parallel time :  2983.89601707  ms
```

Based on [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers), pool spawns independent processes, and i can check that. So it is not the [GIL](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock) problem. What is the reason for slower parallel version?

I have also implemented almost same amount of computation with Process as shown below:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from math import sqrt
from timeit import default_timer as timer

def worker(n):
    out = [ sqrt(i ** 2) for i in range(n)]
    print sum(out)

def parworker(N):
    jobs = []
    nThreads = 4
    NPerThread = N/nThreads

    for i in range(nThreads):
        p = Process(target=worker, args=(NPerThread,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

    for p in jobs:
        p.join()
```

I have benchmarked it with the same input size and same timing functions to get the following execution times:

```
sequential time :  2339.83802795  ms
parallel time :  968.728780746  ms
```

In this case I do get speedup (~2.7x) which make sense to me on my machine. Both Process and Pool utilize process level prarallelism, why do I not get speedup in the first case? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: i think when we add parallel processing i take some additional overhead so for a small functions it take more time than sequential but for time consuming function i work fine

Comment: Could you post the rest of your code, please. What do you import and how do you call your calculate functions? I did a test run and parallel was 30% faster

Comment: One glaring issue is that by default `map` will use a chunksize of `1`, meaning it will send around single numbers and get the result back. Choose a higher number (fiddle a bit around until you find the optimum): `pool.map(squareNumber, numbers, 512)`.

Comment: @Hannu I have added the rest of the code.

Comment: @filmor I tried various chunksizes and the best I could get was 5% improvement for a chuncksize of 2048.

Comment: Thanks. No help from there, I am afraid.  I was hoping there were something to explain the behaviour but this is the test I ran. When I run your code, with chunksize of 512, I get a significant improvement in performance, and parallel beats sequential by a wide margin. As it has been pointed out, your function is rather simple and does not benefit too much from parallel execution.

Comment: @Hannu thanks for trying it out. I have added another example where I do get speedup on the same machine. I will also give it a try on my laptop (which is quite recent) to see if I get better performance there, as you get.